# An Excel table embedded within a Word document loses color (grayscaled) when printed, while the remainder of the document has full color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, printer

I have a Word document with logos, text, etc. in color. Embedded within the document is an Excel table. The Excel table also has colors. When printed from Excel, the colors are as expected. Within Word, the embedded table's colors look fine.

When I print the Word document (or save as a PDF), the Word elements are correctly-colored, but the embedded Excel table is grayscale -- except where some of the word elements overlap the Excel table.

I've never experienced nor heard of such strange behaviour. I have tried recreating the Word document from scratch and re-embedding the Excel table, but this didn't solve the issue. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere the document is made to think it's printing in black and white. Make sure in Excel that you did not select draft quality. Go to File |
Page Setup. On the Sheet tab, make sure that "Black and white" (or "Draft
quality") is not checked. Then try to embed the excel sheet again.

If this does not help, try to copy the content of your document into a new Word document but first make sure that you have a color printer selected by default in that document.

Comment: Draft/B&W i have tripple checked. And Point two is exactly what i meant by i made the same File new from scratch. According to many Forums i've read. I came to the conclusion that the new Office 2013 is still a bit buggy. Also if i print the Same File from another PC it works as expected. As far as i have prooved that it may be the Office installation on that One PC that causes the Problem. I'll do a fresh Office installation and let You know if that solved the Problem. Thaks

Comment: it was the office installation